# List of String to Map

Tags: elixir

I want to convert this set of list that I split from .txt file:

```rb
["a: 1", "b: 2", "c: 3"]
```

to:

```rb
%{"a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c" => "3"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item <- ["a: 1", "b: 2", "c: 3"], into: %{} do
  [k, v] = String.split(item, ": ")
  {k, v}
end
# %{"a" => "1"}, %{"b" => "2"}, %{"c" => "3"}
```

Comment: [`List.to_tuple/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html?#to_tuple/1): `for ..., do: item |> String.split(": ") |> List.to_tuple()`.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to use the universal [`reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2):

```
list = ["a: 1", "b: 2", "c: 3"]
Enum.reduce(list, %{}, fn <<a::binary-size(1)>> <> ": " <> <<b::binary-size(1)>>, acc -> Map.put(acc, a, b) end)
```

Or another way would be to use [`into/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2):

```
Enum.into(list, %{}, fn <<a::binary-size(1)>> <> ": " <> <<b::binary-size(1)>> -> {a, b} end)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just out of curiosity:

```rb
list = ["a: 1", "b: 2", "c: 3"]

<<?%, ?{, Enum.join(list, ",") :: binary, ?}>>
|> Code.eval_string()
|> elem(0)
#⇒ %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Please note that conversion to a map is doomed when the input has several values for the same key:

```rb
list = ["a: 1", "a: 2", "a: 3"]

<<?%, ?{, Enum.join(list, ",") :: binary, ?}>>
|> Code.eval_string()
|> elem(0)
#⇒ %{a: 3}
```

That’s why it’s better to convert the input to [`Keyword`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html?).

**In general, one should probably modify the code that produces this weird input to return a `Keyword` instead in the first place.**